# Active Storage: TypeError: no explicit conversion of Symbol into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I'm having a bit of trouble with using Active Storage on a Rails 5.2 app, which I only recently started building.

As an experiment, I set up a fresh rails application and set up Active Storage as the first thing, then built out a new scaffold, and it worked on the fresh application.

To really boil this down, if I go to the rails console for the non-working application, I get this:

```
> rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 47792
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.1)
[1] pry(main)> ActiveStorage
=> ActiveStorage
[2] pry(main)> ActiveStorage::Blob
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
from (erb):12:in `[]'
```

In the working application, I get this:

```
> rails c
Running via Spring preloader in process 48340
Loading development environment (Rails 5.2.1)
irb(main):001:0> ActiveStorage
=> ActiveStorage
irb(main):002:0> ActiveStorage::Blob
=> ActiveStorage::Blob (call 'ActiveStorage::Blob.connection' to establish a connection)
```

For whatever reason, it appears that Active Storage is only partially loaded. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you "Run rails active_storage:install to copy over active_storage migrations."?

Comment: I ran `rails active_storage:install` and `rails db:migrate`, as per the Rails guide for Active Storage.

Comment: Maybe something in the configuration? This error comes up when you treat an array like an hash so ‘array[:somesymbol]’

Comment: I"m getting this error after switching from `MiniMagic` to `Vips`

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough, after removing all commented lines in my `storage.yml`, Active Storage worked. So the solution is to remove all comments in `storage.yml`.